# Create Mesh op in a certain collection?

Tags: collections

If you have a python script in Blender 2.8 that uses a primitive mesh generator like bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(collection="???")

It will be created in the active selected (in outliner) collection.
You can create and 'Empty' and 'parent' it to that, and even 'link' it into that newly created group 'Empty' (for hierarchical reasons).

```
ob.parent = EmptyGroup

bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

The problem is the newly create mesh has **not** been added to the current collection until after this function completes.

I tried to create a function to purge it from all other collections but as I mentioned that won't work because it's not registered there until after the creating function completes.

```
def cleanUpCollectionMess(ob, trgColl=None):
    if trgColl == None:
        trgColl = bpy.context.scene.collection
    obs = trgColl.objects
    if ob.name in obs.keys() == False:
        trgColl.objects.link(ob)
    colls = bpy.data.collections
    for coll in colls:
        print("cleanUpCollectionMess: check collection:" + coll.name)
        if coll != trgColl:
            obs = coll.objects
            print("cleanUpCollectionMess: check for:" + ob.name + " in:" + str(obs.keys()))
            if ob.name in obs.keys() == True:
                print("cleanUpCollectionMess: Found unlinking:" + ob.name)
                obs.unlink(ob)
```

[I am editing this code but it doesn't work for the reasons I explained besides the fact that it doesn't seems to find the ob.name in the obs.keys()
If you take the True out it works??!!

```
res = ob.name in obs.keys()
type(res)
<class 'bool'>
denominator:<attribute 'denominator' of 'int' objects>
imag:<attribute 'imag' of 'int' objects>
numerator:<attribute 'numerator' of 'int' objects>
real:<attribute 'real' of 'int' objects>
res == True
False
```

]

Okay so this works better now...

```
def cleanUpCollectionMess(ob, trgColl=None):
    if trgColl == None:
        trgColl = bpy.context.scene.collection
    obs = trgColl.objects
    if not ob.name in obs.keys():
        log.info("cleanUpCollectionMess: linking:" + ob.name)
        trgColl.objects.link(ob)
    colls = bpy.data.collections
    for coll in colls:
        log.info("cleanUpCollectionMess: check collection:" + coll.name)
        if coll != trgColl:
            obs = coll.objects
            log.info("cleanUpCollectionMess: check for:" + ob.name + " in:" + str(obs.keys()))
            if ob.name in obs.keys():
                log.info("cleanUpCollectionMess: Found unlinking:" + ob.name)
                obs.unlink(ob)
```

Object is not yet found in the collection when it runs but appears there unwanted after execution completes finished.

It would be nice to have all Mesh creating Ops primitives
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_*
have an argument that is what 'collection' (by name or object) it should be created in.
I am uncertain how to tell it to select the newly created Empty as a Collection since again I'm not sure it exists yet. Maybe the only option in 2.8**0** is to set a timer to clean up the mess these new collections have caused existing code I am trying to fix in regards to when python scripts are generating geometry.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated. Maybe I've done something wrong but again this all worked fine prior in 2.79 *[until the nightmare of collections came to be.]*

Again so simple if the primitive generator operator functions had an argument to assign new meshes upon creation, or something similarly intelligent.

Comment: These problems may have also been related to the primitive geometry generator being in Edit Mode for Beveling, etc.?

Comment: I think should not 'if ob.name in obs.keys() == True:' but 'if ob.name in obs.keys():' (same thing with False, of course)  Not only formalism but probably the cause of your issue